# how to pass id in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this error . I'm using users using Omniauth-identity and Omniauth-FB TWITTER from railscast video.

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/generators/new"
```

when i click

```
<%= link_to 'GENERATE RAPD PRIMER',new_user_generator_path(@user), id:'new' %></li>
```

What this route does in rake routes is

```
new_user_generator GET    /users/:user_id/generators/new(.:format)      generators#new
```

When i click

```
<%= link_to 'GENERATE RAPD PRIMER',user_generator_results_path(@user), id:'new' %></li>
```

my URL returns

```
http://localhost:3000/users//generators/new
```

There's no id return in that URL. How come ??? How can i fix it? I'm using railscast tutorial about Omniauth FB and Identity for User model. I'm trying to associate User with generator.

Comment: your route is specifying `new_user_generator` and you are using `user_generator_results`..why??

Comment: oops sorry is suppose to be new_user_generator_path(@user). But i'mstill getting error

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you pass `user_id` param as per routes:

```
new_user_generator_path(user_id: @user.id)
```

Comment: Because `@user` is nil

Comment: but i've alrady login in my program. Do i need  User Controller to solve this issue ? currently i can't see any link between my login with the user. I tried rails console ( User.all) there's an user_id and etc) . I think the problem occurs bcoz there's no User controller to pass the id. i'm following railscast tutorial about omniauth-fb and omniauth-identity

Comment: you need to assign User object to `@user`. For example: `@user = User.first`. Probably in controller.

Comment: i did assign this in application controller 
def current_user
      current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end

Comment: now it works 
<%= link_to 'GENERATE RAPD PRIMER',new_user_generator_path(current_user.id), id:'new' %></li>
      <%= link_to 'VIEW RESULT HISTORY', user_generators_path(current_user.generators),id:'view'%></li>

Comment: but whenever i want to generate new RAPD primer, after finish my form, i clicked submit, it's suppose to direct me the index page showing the records of this user but it's showing me error uninitialized user controller